# How to turn a Python array into Mathematica List?

Tags: list-manipulation, python

I am running

```
a = RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "python2 fit.py"]
```

which returns

> "[ 0.04044647  0.75243326 -0.42992283]\n[ 0.04163976  0.15076435  0.31245249]\n"

How to turn it into a Mathematica expression?

Comment: I assume you are looking for something more sophisticated than `ToExpression[StringReplace[..., {"[ " -> "{{", "]\n[ " -> "},{", "]" -> "}}", " " -> ","}]]`, right?

Comment: Well, I thought there is something more direct, some `FromPythonExpression` or so.

Comment: There is an export type"Python expression"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python lists have to have commas in between the numbers. With that fixed, we can use `ImportString` on each line individually:

```
ImportString["[ 0.04044647, 0.75243326, -0.42992283]", "PythonExpression"]
```

> `{0.0404465, 0.752433, -0.429923}`

Comment: Hm, looks I need to figure out why python is giving me an array without commas :/

Comment: @corey979 I would guess that you are using NumPy or something that uses NumPy under the hood, where the string representation of the array gives you space delimited arrays when printed.  You could convert the NumPy array to a python list using tolist() and lists should be printed as comma delimited.  For example, print(a[0].tolist()).

Comment: @TimLaska Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An inelegant but functional solution:

```
test = "[ 0.04044647 0.75243326 -0.42992283]\n[ 0.04163976 0.15076435 0.31245249]\n";

Select[ToExpression[StringSplit[test, {" ", "[", "]"}]], NumberQ]
```

> {0.0404465, 0.752433, -0.429923, 0.0416398, 0.150764, 0.312452}

Or if the list should be divided by "\n" first:

```
ToExpression[StringSplit[StringSplit[test, "\n"], {" ", "[", "]"}]]
```

> {{0.0404465, 0.752433, -0.429923}, {0.0416398, 0.150764, 0.312452}}